# MutationObserver - how to listen to class changes of a certain element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers

I have a slider and want to fire an event depending on which slide is active. Since the slider itself is out of my control, I'm going for a mutationObserver solution with listening to class changes on the slides.

This is what I have so far, but it's not even getting to the console.log part. What could be the issue? It throws no errors, it just doesn't work.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $slides = $("#hero-slider .swiper-slide");

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      if (mutation.attributeName === "class") {
        console.log('mutationobs worked');

        if (($('#hero-slider .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active').attr('data-swiper-slide-index') == 0) || ($('#hero-slider .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-duplicate-active').attr('data-swiper-slide-index') == 0)) {
          $('#landing-hero .elementor-shape').css('z-index', '0');
        } else if (($('#hero-slider .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active').attr('data-swiper-slide-index') == 1) || ($('#hero-slider .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-duplicate-active').attr('data-swiper-slide-index') == 1)) {
          $('#landing-hero .elementor-shape').css('z-index', '5');
        }
      }
    });
  });

  observer.observe($slides[0], {
    attributes: true
  });
});
```

Comment: `$slides[0]` only ever selects the first slide. You need a loop to add the observer to all slides. If this still doesn't solve your issue then we need to see a working example, including relevant HTML/CSS, in order to recreate the issue.

Comment: If we're talking about [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/) then just listen for the [`slideChange`](https://swiperjs.com/api/#events) event

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, but unfortunately that's not the issue. I'm thinking it might be related to the fact that observe is obsolete now?

Comment: Nope, MutationObserver is very much active still. It sounds like @Andreas has the best solution though, assuming that's the correct library

Comment: @Andreas thanks, checking it out! Sounds like a nice solution. Although I have no idea how to do that if I'm not in control of initializing swiper?

Comment: I will let this unanswered as a homework to improve your Google-Fu ;)

Comment: Don't forget to add an answer if this is the correct library. Otherwise add the one you're using.